# git push error with bitbucket private repository

Tags: git

i've a problem with git. When i push the repo, the result is:

```
piero@jarvis:~/~dev/secure-password$ git commit -m 'Initial commit with contributors'
[master (root-commit) faf8365] Initial commit with contributors
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 contributors.txt
piero@jarvis:~/~dev/secure-password$ git push -u origin master
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
piero@jarvis:~/~dev/secure-password$
```

Comment: Did you generate and upload public key to your bitbucket account?

Comment: yes, i add the plublic key

Comment: you have not added your public key. Generate public key and add in bitbucket account. [check this](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/)

Comment: Is your private key placed in `~/.ssh`?

Comment: piero@jarvis:~/.ssh$ ls -a
.  ..  id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts